# Bash go to level 1 subdir if inside parentsubdir

Tags: bash, shell

Okay,

I would like to do the following in the shell.

If I am in a subdir like `css` which is inside a subdir like `mypage` (e.g. `projects/mypage/htdocs/css`) I would like to go into the root dir of the project, which is `mypage`. I would like to write this as a function to us as a command. The only "fixed" value is `projects`.

So basically if I am within any subdir of projects in the shell and I type the command `goroot` (or whatever) I want the function to check if it is in fact inside a subdir of projects and if so, go to the  current subdir.

E.g.

```
~/projects/mypage/htdocs/css › goroot [hit return]   
~/projects/mypage > [jumped to here]
```

Is this at all possible and if so how could I achieve this?

Comment: @anubhava When you're in `~/projects/otherpage/foo`, you want to go to `~/projects/otherpage`, not to `~/projects/mypage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I am understanding correctly, this should work:

```
goroot() { cd $(sed -r 's#(~/projects/[^/]*)/.*#\1#' <<< $PWD); }
```

This `sed` command effectively strips off everything after `~/projects/SOMETHING` and then changes to that directory. If you're not in `~/projects/` then it will leave you in the current directory.

Note: this assumes that `$PWD` uses the `~` to denote home, if it is something like `/home/user/` then amend the `sed` command appropriately.

Comment: I had to change `-r` to `-E`because I am on osx and had to amend the sed as you said, because of the PWD content. With this it works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
projroot=/home/user/projects

goroot() {
    # Strip off project root prefix.
    local m=${d#$projroot/}
    if [ "$m" = "$d" ]; then
        echo "Not in ~/projects"
        return
    fi

    # Strip off project directory.
    local suf=${m#*/}
    if [ "$suf" = "$m" ]; then
        echo "Already in project root."
        return
    fi

    # cd to concatenation of project root, and project directory (stripped of sub-project path).
    cd "$projroot/${m%/$suf}"
}
```